# compute dz[1] applying chain rule

Tags: chain-rule

In Andrew Ng course, we need to compute dz[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYGsL.png) in a NN with 2 hidden layers.

So why we don't compute da[2] in order to properly do the chain rule/back-propagation?

why this is correct ?

$\frac{(dL)}{(dz[1])} = \frac{(dL)}{(dz[2])} * \frac{(dz[2])}{(da[1])} * \frac{(da[1])}{(dz[1])} $

and this is not?

$\frac{(dL)}{(dz[1])} = \frac{(dL)}{(da[2])} * \frac{(da[2])}{(dz[2])} * \frac{(dz[2])}{(da[1])}  * \frac{(da[1])}{(dz[1])} $

[graph of NN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYGsL.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: ok, I will try, thank you José